# Can an iframe know if it is in viewport? The ifram is not of same origin

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe that goes inside another page. I do not have control over the other page content, and they are not of same origin. I want to do some actions only when a user sees the iframe. Can I determine from inside the iframe if it is in the viewport?

Comment: While you can detect if your page is in an iframe, since the outer page is on another domain and likely doesn't grant CORS permission, you won't be able to detect if the iframe element is in view. The iframe element itself is what would need to be checked and is part of the outer page's content.

Comment: @Ouroborus Can I detect some child of the iframe element? Say `body`?

Comment: No. The view area, as far as the iframe's content is concerned, is the iframe view area, not the browser view area.